# List of classes in project Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, reflection

I am playing around with some reflection in Objective C (iOS app) and building a customized testing environment, and I am trying to get a list of classes that I have created in my project, so I can iterate over these and look for certain method declarations by using reflection.

My problem is to retrieve that list. I do not want to manually type in each class into a list or some static field in my reflection class, but instead let it be generic for any project.

The list could be a list of class names, or objects of the type `Class`.

I did manage to find the `objc_getClassList()` function in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html
But this creates a list of ALL classes, and I wouldn't be able to determine which are user defined and which are not. I have tried to seek guidance around the Internet, but without luck finding an answer or similar question.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
Now I also tried to use `objc_copyImageNames()` in hope that I would be able to find my project as an image, and then use `objc_copyClassNamesForImage()` to get the list, but with no luck as the project is not considered an image, Worth a shoot I guess.

Comment: You might try calling class_getVersion and seeing if you can do something with that.

Comment: And if your user classes are well-behaved you can eliminate all UI and NS classes, and maybe one or two other prefixes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the code from the `objc_getClassList()` documentation
and check each class with `[NSBundle bundleForClass:class]` if it is defined in your
application:

```
int numClasses;
Class * classes = NULL;

classes = NULL;
numClasses = objc_getClassList(NULL, 0);

if (numClasses > 0 )
{
    classes = (__unsafe_unretained Class *)malloc(sizeof(Class) * numClasses);
    numClasses = objc_getClassList(classes, numClasses);
    for (int i = 0; i < numClasses; i++) {
        Class c = classes[i];
        NSBundle *b = [NSBundle bundleForClass:c];
        if (b == [NSBundle mainBundle]) {
            NSLog(@"%s", class_getName(c));
            // ...
        }
    }
    free(classes);
}
```

Comment: Nice, this gets me most of the way, although all the Cocos2D files are still present. I will investigate the NSBundle class further.

Comment: On another note, why do you cast the pointer from malloc with `__unsafe_unretained` ?

Comment: @ArniDat: The cast is necessary if you compile with ARC, otherwise the compiler will complain about an invalid conversion of void *.

Comment: @ArniDat: The Cocos2D classes are defined in your bundle, so the runtime makes no difference between Cocos2D classes and other classes that *you* defined. Checking the class name (from `class_getName(c)`) as Hot Licks suggested above might help.

Comment: Ah al right, thanks for the clarification. If anyone is curious; I decided to let the user specify a class-name-prefix and then compare the prefix to the resulting list of classes. This still does not guarantee that only my classes are run, but does limit the 'error'-rate a great bunch.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on a library, than I would suggest creating a custom class, that would keep a list of other classes.

```
// XYZLibRegister.h

@interface XYZLibRegister : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSArray *classArray;

+ (void)registerClassNameString:(NSString *)clsNameString;

@end
```

Add a static NSMutableArray in .m file and initialize it in + (void)load method.

```
// XYZLibRegister.m

NSMutableArray *classArray;

@implementation XYZLibRegister

- (void)classArray
{
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:classArray];
}

+ (void)load
{
    classArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

+ (void)registerClassNameString:(NSString *)clsNameString
{
    [classArray addObject:clsNameString];
}

@end
```

Then you could use it in your library classes, hiding that in your .m files.

```
// XYZYourClass.m

#include "XYZLibRegister.h"

@implementation XYZYourClass

+ (void)load
{
    [XYZLibRegister registerClassNameString:NSStringFromClass([this class])];
}

@end
```

Now you can use XYZLibRegister class as your library register.

I'd also suggest you to study NSObject Class Reference.